# Using json in msg

Tags: ros, ros2, msg

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Is it good practice to use the ros2 json message, ie, in a standard message like std_msgs / string, write a string with a json structure?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/314920/using-json-in-msg/) by [D0l0RES](https://answers.ros.org/users/38314/d0l0res/) on ROS Answers with karma: 23 on 2019-02-07

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

> Is it good practice to use the ros2 json message, ie, in a standard message like std_msgs / string, write a string with a json structure?

I would say "no".

One of the main points of using standardised messages as we do in ROS is that they allow you to encode both [syntax](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Syntax_(logic)) (ie: the exact *form* of data (layout, sizes of fields, etc)) and the [semantics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semantics_of_logic) (ie: the meaning (so `x` is the first element of a `vector` that has its origin at `frame_id`)) in a single definition.

This allows both consumers and producers of such messages to be very explicit about the information they are communicating, and allows things like decoupling in time (ie: a consumer that receives messages that were produced 2 years ago should still be able to interpret them).

Your suggestion essentially comes down to using a field of type `string` and populating it with data that syntactically fits that field perfectly fine (a JSON string is still a `string`), but semantically seems like a bad fit: a JSON string is *not* just a `string`, it's (typically) actually a stringified (ie: serialised) representation of some higher order data structure (such as a list, map or even worse: arbitrary application-specific classes).

Interpretation of that `string` field now has two "layers" (in contrast to the 'normal' situation where we use only appropriate msg types):

1. the middleware layer where the sequence of bytes coming in as part of a message is supposed to be a `string`
2. the application layer where "special knowledge" is required to know that this string is not just a string, but actually requires interpretation *again* to be able to get the actual message content out of it

We could say that "special knowledge" (ie: layer 2) is always required to be able to interpret a message, but the main difference here is that by using properly typed messages the special knowledge is (at least partly) embedded in *the contract that exists between the producer and consumer*: it's the semantics part of the message definition. That is very powerful, as it greatly reduces coupling between the producer and consumer: very little knowledge of the internals of the producer are imported into the consumer, making things like replacing components and mixing-and-matching components to create applications a lot easier, as neither will assume (too much) about the other.

If producer `A` starts putting JSON (or anything that is not actually really a plain `string`) into a field, the correct interpretation of that field completely depends on consumer `B` *knowing* that field contains JSON (and not just an arbitrary plain string). This couples `A` and `B`, as they both must assume their communication channel works that way, or they can't function.

To make it more explicit: even though the message definition tells me that consumer `B` accepts a `string`, if I send it anything but JSON, `B` will fail to process the message, even though both syntax and semantics have been adhered to (but note that `string` is a less-than-ideal type for this sort of communication as well, see below).

---

Note that a similar argument can be made for all message types in the `std_msgs` package: a `std_msgs/String` doesn't convey much semantics, neither does publishing a temperature measurement as a `std_msgs/Float64`. That is also the reason that direct usage of messages in `std_msgs` is discouraged: it's always better to use a more semantically meaningful type for your topics, as that will allow consumers to reuse the contract (ie: knowledge) that comes with those message types.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2019-02-07

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2019-02-07**:
Note: I'm not an expert, so this is my opinion, based on some years of ROS usage and my background.

**Comment by [VictorLamoine](https://answers.ros.org/users/20682/victorlamoine/) on 2019-02-07**:
This question is similar to mine: https://answers.ros.org/question/302648/custom-message-with-variable-fields/.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2019-02-07**:
@VictorLamoine: I'm not sure actually. Using polymorphism (as you suggest in your question) would maintain syntax and semantics (to a certain degree), while throwing typing out of the window (which using JSON in a `string` field is akin to imo) does not.